# How to style div inside fluid container div whose height is equal but overflow-y is scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a chat window where the internal div scrolls horizontally and viewable area fills the the height of the container div.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="messages" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:100%; width:100%; vertical-align:bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The container div's width and height is fluid and the messages div should fill it 100%. I'm not entirely sure i need the container at all.. but assuming because of the scollable nature of the messages div i will need a container.

Comment: use `max-height` attribute and then true to `overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: hi manoz do you mind writing exactly what you mean? would be appreciated. thanks!